# What is the most efficient way to insert a value into an integer ranked list?

Tags: python, django, database

I have a database that has a list of "Experience Levels", using Django Python.

Each level comes with a unique rank attribute, which is a positive integer greater than one. The lower value rank is the first skill on a dropdown, and the highest value rank is the last, so a "Senior" with rank 3 is also everything below.

I am creating an endpoint to update and insert values into this ranked list but I am having a lot of issues.

In order to insert a new value, I need to change everything above the new rank and then insert it in. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Edit: Adding code.

```
class ExperienceLevel(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
  experience_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
  rank = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)], unique=True, default=1)
```

So in the database I may have something like this:

```
{
  "id": uuid,
  "experience_level": "junior",
  "rank": 1
}

{
  "id": uuid,
  "experience_level": "senior,
  "rank": 2
}
```

If I want to add a new experience_level between junior and senior, on the front end I would call the API and update each `experience_level` a certain way multiple times, but I cannot figure out a good way to do accomplish this with the backend.

I am thinking of adding in a Manager that gives me all the `experience_levels` that are greater than a certain rank (the new experience level).

Then I can go through the loop and increment each `rank` by 1, and then insert the new rank.

I could create a manager:

```
class ExperienceManager(models.Manager):
  def get_queryset(self, rank):
    return super().get_queryset().filter(rank_gte=rank).order_by('-rank')
```

And add it to the ExperienceLevel model.

```
greater_than = ExperienceManager
```

And on PUT, get a list of all the ranks higher than the new target rank and add one to their rank values.

Comment: Share your code (models and views) please

Comment: You mean if you insert a new rank between 2 and 3, that becomes the new 3 and old 3 needs to become 4? Please share what you've done so far.

Comment: @Wariored added some code and ideas

Comment: Is there any requirement for `rank` to be `IntegerField`?
I mean the problem of updating ranks greater than a specific value will be fixed by defining `rank` as `FloatField`.

Comment: @partizaans I don't think I follow, can you explain further?

Comment: If the `rank` is just used to keep ordering of `ExperienceLevel` objects, you can use `FloatField` instead of `PositiveIntegerField` and on insertion of the new record you just need to find a number between higher and lower rank (average for example). Like this, you won't need to update other records on each insert.

Comment: @partizaans Can you give me an example of how one "insert" would go?

Comment: Consider there are two `ExperienceLevel` of junior and senior with the rank value of 1 and 2 respectively. The user decides to insert "mid-level" which should get placed between junior (rank=1) and senior (rank=2). The frontend calculates `avg(1, 2)` as the rank value of mid-level which is going to be inserted. You can do this for further insertions recursively. For example "upper mid-level" will have `avg(1.5, 2)` and "lower mid-level"  will have `avg(1, 1.5)` calculated as rank values. All of these are considered while `rank` has no meaning but the priority for ordering.